# Trying to count total from repeat names

Tags: excel, count, bioinformatics

I am not sure how to explain it in words but having a look at the table will make it clear.
[screen shot of Data from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKRvR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To auto count try-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A1:A16),y,COUNTIF(A1:A16,x),CHOOSE({1,2},x,y))
```

For auto sum-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A1:A16),y,SUMIF(A1:A16,x,B1:B16),CHOOSE({1,2},x,y))
```

[image]